# How to achieve responsive accordion with isotope and bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm afraid i'm a pretty weak developer but i'd like to incorporate an accordion to view case studies within my isotope portfolio a la Click3X.com/portfolio. My site is bootstrap responsive. Not sure of the best and cleanest way to go about it... I couldn't find much online so I'm hoping one of you may have some clues or could direct me to a plugin. Would I use an iframe to load the entire page layout within the accordion? Thanks for any assistance with this.

Comment: Welcome to the site - sorry to hear the plight.  Generally we see downvotes here unless you provide more information about what you've tried, your strategy for a solution, etc.   I will mark to leave this open, but Can you go into more detail?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041876/integrating-bootstrap-with-isotope),  and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627338/jquery-isotope-and-twitter-bootstrap-grid).  Or [buy one and integrate it](https://wrapbootstrap.com/tag/isotope)